# How I can convert date to char and then ti number?

Tags: sql, oracle, data-conversion

Please help to sole this task. I need convert date to char and then to number, so that i can perform arithmetic operation and divide the date by 2.

```
select (sysdate+30+30+89)/2 from dual;
```

This query doesn't work and i have no idea how i can convert date to number.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  Dividing a date in half doesn't make sense.

Comment: 12 months in a year. I need to find half of this time period.

Comment: . . That is 6 months.  I have no idea what that even has to do with `sysdate`, but much less date or integer conversions.

Comment: Lets say that the date is "This Tuesday" (it doesn't matter what the actual date of "This Tuesday" is) then what do you expect to happen when you add 30 to "This Tuesday"? What are the units of the "30"? Similarly, what do you expect to happen when you divide "This Tuesday" by 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the understanding of the question I think you need the current day of the year to perform arithmetic operation

```
  SELECT (to_number(to_char(sysdate,'DDD'))+30+30+89)/2 from dual;
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. This is exactly what i want to do.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolves your problem

Answer (score 1):

The only sensible reason that I can think of for doing something like this is to get the midpoint of two dates, where one is `sysdate`.

If that is what you are trying to do, subtract the dates and divide by 2.  Dividing an *interval* in half makes sense.  Then add the resulting interval back to one of the dates.

For instance:

```
select date '2020-01-01' + (sysdate - date '2020-01-01') / 2
from dual
```